# UI is not Updating ( Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app

I am learning React and learned some basics, so utilizing that knowledge by making this basic project.
I was making a Simple Notes Keeping Application using React and Firebase.

Data is perfectly transferred to the Firebase DataBase ✅.

fetching data ✅.

The problem I am facing is that the fetched data is not updating in UI.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AiFillCaretUp } from 'react-icons/ai';
import './Card.css';

export default function Card(props) {
  const [showPara, setShowPara] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  console.log('inside card');

  useEffect(() => {
    let notesData = [];
    console.log('inside UseEffect');
    const fetchNote = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://notes-keeper-react-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/notes.json');
      const data = await response.json();
      for (const key in data) {
        notesData.push({ id: key, title: data[key].title, note: data[key].note });
      }
    };
    fetchNote();
    // console.log(notesData);
    setData(notesData);
  }, []);

  const toggleHandler = () => {
    setShowPara((preVal) => !preVal);
  };

  const paraClass = showPara ? 'card-para toggle' : 'card-para';
  const rotate = showPara ? 'icon rotate' : 'icon';
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      {console.log('inside card container', data)}

      {data.map((card) => (
        <div className='card' key={card.id}>
          <div className='card-title' onClick={toggleHandler}>
            <h3>{card.title}</h3>
            <AiFillCaretUp className={rotate} />
          </div>
          <div className={paraClass}>
            <p>{card.note}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

showing Data inside this

```
{console.log('inside card container', data)}
```

But this is not Working

```
{data.map((card) => (
    <div className='card' key={card.id}>
      <div className='card-title' onClick={toggleHandler}>
        <h3>{card.title}</h3>
        <AiFillCaretUp className={rotate} />
      </div>
      <div className={paraClass}>
        <p>{card.note}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

I hope you are understanding what is the problem.

Comment: Try adding data && data.map() as my assumption is the data got undefined at first when console log

Comment: you have an useless variable called fetchNote, since you are using async function to fetch the details and save the data into state inside that async function. why are you using `fetchnote()` again. try removing that.

Comment: Move `setData(notesData);` below(after) the closing of `for` loop inside `fetchNote` function

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks for the Help.
There is one more Problem in this code. like on the UI it's showing two Card Div. when I click any one div They both collapse and expand. how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let notesData = [];
    const fetchNote = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://notes-keeper-react-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/notes.json');
      const data = await response.json();
      for (const key in data) {
        notesData.push({ id: key, title: data[key].title, note: data[key].note });
      }
      setData(notesData); // data is ready here
    };
    fetchNote();
  }, []);
```

`fetchNote` is an async function so it takse some time to do its job and get the data. So you should wait until the data is ready and unfortunately the data is not ready when you use `setData(notesData)` right after calling `fetchNote()`

**Alternatively** you can return the data inside async function and it automatically returns another promise that resolves to the data you want and there you can update your data:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let notesData = [];
    const fetchNote = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://notes-keeper-react-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/notes.json');
      const data = await response.json();
      for (const key in data) {
        notesData.push({ id: key, title: data[key].title, note: data[key].note });
      }
      return notesData; // returns a promise that resolves to 'notesData'
    };

    fetchNote()
      .then((updatedData) => {
        setData(updatedData);
      })
  }, []);
```

Comment: There is one more Problem in this code. like on the UI it's showing two Card Div.
when I click any one div They both collapse and expand. 
how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchNote()` is an asynchronous function, it returns a promise and you will have to wait until fetching the data. It will take some time to get the data from the database. Since you set the `notesData` immediately without waiting for the response using `await` keyword, it sets the empty array value to the data state.

You can await for the `fetchNote()` before setting the data or you can set the data inside the `fetchNote()` function after for loop.

```
const fetchNote = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://notes-keeper-react-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/notes.json');
      const data = await response.json();
      for (const key in data) {
        notesData.push({ id: key, title: data[key].title, note: data[key].note });
      }

      //set the data here
      setData(notesData);
};
```

Comment: setting state like this is completely fine `Object.keys(response).map((res) => {
      return setCardData([...cardData, { id: res, value: response[res] }]);
    });`